# Visual Studio no longer displays "Show Potential Fixes"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Suddenly I can no longer see the option to show potential fixes when hovering over a squiggled item. I don't understand why this option disappeared.

[image]

Comment: This feature cannot be turned off. if Ctrl + . does not help, close it and open it again.

Comment: Restarting the Visual Studio should do the work. Sometimes happens on my computer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the shortcut.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You want to hover over the item and hold your control key, this should display your error correction menu. If not it's most likely a settings issue, you can contact Microsoft support for quick efficient help, it's been awhile since I've dabbled in visual studio.
Here's a link to their visual studio help center. I hope you work it out!
https://www.visualstudio.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the current project does not have a direct reference to the type of one of the parameters.
e.g
I am working in a client app and want to use Code suggestions to add a function to an interface:

```
Guid userId = securityInterface.ImportLegacyUser(realmName, newUser);
```

The ImportLegacyUser function is highlighted as not found, but there is no suggestion to create it. Even after I added the interface member manually, the error appeared in the intellisense, but it built correctly.

The type of newUser, is defined in a dependency of the library contained in the interface. Adding a direct project dependency to the library containing the type definition enabled Visual Studio to track the definition again.